# How to find python and python3 config directories for Homebrew installation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, homebrew

I installed `python` and `python3` using Homebrew on Mac OS X (Yosemite 10.10.5). But I don't know where the relevant config directories are. How can I find them?

Comment: Homebrew puts everything in `/usr/local/Cellar`, have you tried looking there?

Comment: `ls -l /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/config-3.4m` Is there the config directory? @jonrsharpe

Comment: "Relevant" config here is the point to me: Sometimes this is home brew that one wants to know where, but other times it is the installed app (python in this case with pip as specific package manager) that selects some active place, some linked location etc.

Comment: Are you not in a position to answer that question yourself by looking at it? What configuration are you trying to set, exactly?

Comment: I want to know if there is command to locate the python/python3 config directory? @jonrsharpe

Comment: And *what do you mean by config directory?* Again, what configuration are you trying to set?

Comment: Compiling vim to support python and python3. There is a configure --with-python3-config-dir, which I need to know where the config directory is. @jonrsharpe

Comment: Well why not *put that in the question?* The examples I could find seem to be things like `/usr/lib/python3.4/config-3.4m-x86_64-linux-gnu`, so why not try the one you've found and see what happens?

Answer (score 8):

Try using the `ls` option of `brew`:

```
brew ls python
```

Answer (score 6):

Asking the provider always goes a long way:

```
$ brew info python3
```

On my machine - an El Capitan - it currently states:

```
python3: stable 3.5.2 (bottled), devel 3.6.0a3, HEAD
Interpreted, interactive, object-oriented programming language
https://www.python.org/
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1 (3,659 files, 53.2M)
  Poured from bottle on 2015-12-08 at 06:59:56
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2 (7,717 files, 109.3M) *
  Built from source on 2016-07-11 at 10:37:37
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/python3.rb

# - - 8 < - -
They will install into the site-package directory
  /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages
```

As @MarkSetchell suggest you can also use `ls` which in my system shows:

```
$ brew ls python3
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2/bin/2to3-3.5
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2/bin/easy_install-3.5
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2/bin/idle3
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2/bin/idle3.5
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2/bin/pip3
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2/bin/pip3.5
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2/bin/pydoc3
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2/bin/pydoc3.5
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2/bin/python3
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2/bin/python3-config
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2/bin/python3.5
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2/bin/python3.5-config
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2/bin/python3.5m
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2/bin/python3.5m-config
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2/bin/pyvenv
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2/bin/pyvenv-3.5
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2/bin/wheel3
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/ (6811 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2/IDLE 3.app/Contents/ (8 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2/lib/pkgconfig/ (3 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2/libexec/pip/ (522 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2/libexec/setuptools/ (242 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2/libexec/wheel/ (93 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2/Python Launcher 3.app/Contents/ (16 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2/share/man/ (2 files)
```

What is confined below `/usr/local/lib` and the specific version "cellar" (here `/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2/` in my experience deserves some care and attention ;-)

Sometimes I forget, and then I do as if I wanted to upgrade a package I installed just to have the matching `pip` print out the path I forgot:

```
$ pip3 install --upgrade requests
Requirement already up-to-date: requests in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages
```

Comment: Note that the line you quote refers to where `pip` will put things, not where Homebrew puts things.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Hm, the command shows them all (updated the answer) or what did you mean by "quote"? Sometimes down votes happen, already while people are so kind to still complete there answer by adding detail or referencing to the answers others did submit in parallel. Is this community shaping ;-) ? PS: I for one find the web interface giving answers hard to use ... leading to multiple passes.